# How to make firefox ask to remember password for a site I previously told it not to

Tags: firefox

I have firefox set to remember passwords.  For one particular site I declined to have firefox remember the password in the past.  I now want to have the password for that site remembered, so is there a way to get firefox to ask me again?

**Edit:**  It turns out the site in question is somehow disabling that feature, so it doesn't ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From within Firefox click on

- Tools (or press the alt key once on your keyboard to display it)
- Options,
- Security tab
- Under passwords, click on Exceptions. Remove the site in question from this list.

Comment: Well, I'm going to look into this, but just as more options (for you or anyone else who reads this post) you can try https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saved-password-editor/

Comment: I also wonder if you have a bug. When you select do not save, it should list it in the excepts, as per the Mozilla site's Q & A http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/763967. And more details generally can be found here http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords

Comment: If this is a new issue (as in it's only just happened), you may need to restart firefox (although I always suggest restart PC to be sure) to reflect any change.

Comment: The site has not asked me for months.  Firefox has been restarted many times since then.   I guess I could clear out the cache...  or maybe the site has some sort of code that can disable the feature (as a security measure)... although that doesn't seem to be the case as I do seem to remember selecting no to the remember password question for that site.

Comment: further... I just tried the site on another computer (one I've never visited the site before on) and it didn't ask to remember... so I guess this site has programming that can disable the feature.

Comment: Just an additional comment, if the site is secure (https://) then it won't save the password. Also, some sites use javascript to prevent this (although I can't find the source now)